# Losing long text strings when assigning array to cells in Excel 2007 using VSTO

Tags: .net, vsto, excel-2007, watin

I found that when assigning long strings into cells via an array, it would randomly drop strings.

For example I have a 2d array (1 row with around 20 values), including an item number and body HTML (from WatiN automation's body Html).

When I assign that array into a row (same size of course), it would occasionally not insert the HTML into its cell, but the values either side of that cell appeared fine.

On the assumption that the strings were just too long, I tried removing unneeded white-space from the HTML and it worked... but not because of the length!

It turns out if I simply trim the string it would work (even if there were no trailing whitespace!).

**What could be in the string itself to cause Excel to reject it and why does a simple string operation (like Trim) fix the problem?**

```
EXCEL.Range range = worksheet.GetRange(1,1,10,10);
object[,] cells = range.GetCells();
cells[1,1] = "123456789";
cells[1,2] = waitnbrowser.Body; // Get 10K body text HTML string
cells[1,3] = "something else";
range.Value = cells; // Sometimes the body text is left out, even though it shows in the cells array fine.
```

If I add a trim to the long string it works, even if the length does not change:

```
cells[1,2] = waitnbrowser.Body.Trim(); // this (or other string manipulation) fixes the problem!
range.Value = cells; // now works every time!
```

Comment: @Keith: Sure, I use my own library of extension methods to get the values, but you get the idea on the setting of them.

Comment: Is it possible there are some untypical [whitespace characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) in the string (ex: form feed, paragraph separator, etc)? (I think you imply you already compared the string length before & after but I'm just trying to make sure all bases are covered.)